# "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError" exception is thrown on using Spreadsheet Service

Tags: java, google-api, google-sheets-api

I am using following code to fetch the spreadsheet and to print the title of sheet.

```
import com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.*;
import com.google.gdata.util.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MySpreadsheetIntegration {
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws AuthenticationException, MalformedURLException, IOException, ServiceException {
        SpreadsheetService service =
                new SpreadsheetService("MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1");

        URL SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL(
                "spreadsheet URL");

        SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL, SpreadsheetFeed.class);
        List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = feed.getEntries();

        for (SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet : spreadsheets) {
            // Print the title of this spreadsheet to the screen
            System.out.println(spreadsheet.getTitle().getPlainText());
        }

    }
}
```

but i am getting exception as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.copyOf([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet;
    at com.google.gdata.wireformats.AltFormat$Builder.setAcceptableTypes(AltFormat.java:399)
    at com.google.gdata.wireformats.AltFormat$Builder.setAcceptableXmlTypes(AltFormat.java:387)
    at com.google.gdata.wireformats.AltFormat.<clinit>(AltFormat.java:49)
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.<clinit>(Service.java:558)
    at myPackage.MySpreadsheetIntegration.main(MySpreadsheetIntegration.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

I didn't find any reason for this error, please help me to solve the problem to fetch the spreadsheet data.

I am using following main jars:

```
gdata-spreadsheet-3.0
mailapi.jar
gdata-core-1.0
```

etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`com.google.common.collect` is part of the [Guava: Google Core Libraries for Java 1.6+](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/). You probably need to download and install them ... `guava-17.0.jar` would appear to be the latest version of the guava jar ...

Comment: After adding this jar, the above mentioned exception is not thrown.